# Mockito stubbing a method to return value for all instances of class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Scenario:

I am testing a Spring MVC controller using a standalone setup.

The controller takes parameters from the JSON object in the request.It calls a service after converting the JSON object to java object.The service saves it to DB using JPA and it then updates the Id field of entity and returns back to controller.The controller returns the JSON response to the caller after converting the entity to JSON.

I have mocked the service in my test class and injected to the controller using @InjectMocks

The mocked service has no access to the private setId method of the JPA entity as it is populated by hibernate in the real scenario.

Now when I mock the service, how can i stub the getId method of the created entity?

Code to test mockservice:

```
@Test
public void thatAccountCreationRendersAsJson() throws Exception {

    doAnswer(new Answer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
    public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
    Account account = (Account) invocationOnMock.getArguments()[0];
    account.setEnabled(true);
    account.setFirstName("bca123");
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }   
    }).when(mockAccountService).registerAccount(any(Account.class),
            anyString(), any(BindingResult.class));
```

Now how to stub the getId method of Account class so that controller gives the Id in the JSON response.

I cannot create a mock account object as it is created by the controller from JSON and sent to the mocked service. my mock account object is not used.

I tried to use

```
Account spier = spy(account);
doReturn(new Long(22)).when(spier).getId();
spier.setFirstName("cba123");
```

in the above doAnswer method but it is not effective.

Is there any way we can return a constant value like 22 for all invocations of getId method of Account.class for any instance ?

http://code.google.com/p/mockito-python/wiki/Stubbing gives a section
Instance, Class-level and Static Methods
which exactly fits my needs where they stub a instance method for all instances 
but it is on python.

Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: Yes we can do that and get the test and functionality done. But was more interested in how can we do something like what we have in the mockito for python. stubbing a method for at class level so that it is applicable for all instances of the created class. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `setId()` method public, and add `account.setId(whatever)`. The `setId()` method has no real reason to be private. Just because Hibernate can set private fields doesn't mean that you shouldn't have a public setter for it, especially if it's needed for your tests. If you really want to keep it private, then do the same thing as Hibernate, and set it using reflection. But I wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved this test to integration testing as i had the full spring container along with a in memory database to set the id by hibernate.

Vam